# JPQL query help: many-to-many relationship filtered by a collection

Tags: jpql

I'm having trouble writing a query using JPQL. I have two entities with a many-to-many relationship:

Entity1 (User)

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private long id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany()
    @JoinTable(name="users_roles", 
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="user_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;
}
```

Entity2 (Role)

```
@Entity
public class Role implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private long id;
    private String name;
}
```

Imagine that I have a list of roles that can vary in size (e.g. "roleA", "roleB", "roleC", ...), and I want to get every user that has every role in this list. In my head, it would be something like this:

```
select u from users u where :roles member of u.roles
```

As far as I know this doesn't work because :roles can't be a collection when used at the left hand side of "member of". Is there a way to achieve this in one JPQL query? If it is not possible in a single query, then what would be the best approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select u FROM User u JOIN u.roles r WHERE r IN (:roles)
```